# Is there any tool through which we can generate SBOM report ( SPDX / CycloneDX) for Windows programs?

Tags: security, trivy, whitesource

Is there any tool through which we can generate SBOM report ( SPDX / CycloneDX) for **Windows programs** ?

There are many tools available which can scan **Linux** OS packages and application packages ( e.g java , maven, .net) like Trivy,Syft,whitesource but it looks like there is no tool available which can generate SBOM report for the applications installed on Microsoft Windows.

Pls suggest.

Thanks
Abdul Mohsin

Answer (score 3):

You can try Microsoft sbom-tool https://github.com/microsoft/sbom-tool

Microsoft provides a tool that you can generate SBOM based on **Microsoft GitHub NuGet package** https://github.com/orgs/microsoft/packages?repo_name=sbom-tool.

This tool support projects that have a .NET project which can ingest packages from nuget.org or only projects that target .NET 6 or higher are supported,

Comment: The way I understand the question (and the thing I'm interested in) *there is no project*, just an installed system (VM image or container) and the goal is to find what is installed on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many tools SBOM generation tools that run on Windows:

- Syft from Anchore
- Microsoft.Sbom.Tool
- Fossa
- MergeBase
- Snyk

Here is a succinct review written by Julius Musseau from which I pulled this list:
https://mergebase.com/blog/best-tools-for-generating-sbom/
The article doesn't explicitly state a date of publication but looking at the source looks like it was published August 2022 and possibly updated in September 2023.

Comment: … of which only MergeBase might actually do what the question asks for – detecting *installed* software – and I'm not exactly sure from the description.